# R - Perform a levene test with two samples with different sizes

Tags: r

So lets say that I have these two arrays with different sizes

[image: values]

And I'd like to perform a levene test with the function leveneTest()

However, the way I have been taught converts these to a dataframe and then calls the function melt to make a data structure readable by the function. This ends up repopulating the smallest array so that both arrays have the same size.

```
dataServers <- as.data.frame(cbind(down25,down27)) #dataServers is 124*2 now
dataServers <- melt(dataServers,variable.name="Server",value.name="DownTimes")
leveneTest(DownTimes~Server,dataServers,center=mean)
```

What would be the easiest way around this?

Comment: I've deleted the RStudio tag because this is a plain R question. Please don't misuse the RStudio tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply `stack` your two samples, of different sizes, into one data frame and perform the `leveneTest`:

```
stacked <- stack(list(down25=down25,down27=down27))
car::leveneTest(values~ind,data=stacked,center=mean)
```

Comment: When you `cbind` columns of different length, R repeats the values in the smaller column until the lengths become equal. You need to replace `cbind` and `melt` with a different function, such as `stack`.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just make them independent dataframes add an identifier column to each and then do an R bind and run the test?  I can make up a full example if that helps that is reproducible.

make dataframe1 with id and value
dataframe2 with id and value
rbind the two together and skip the melt step